# Prove $\sqrt{a+4b}+\sqrt{b+4c}+\sqrt{c+4a}\le 3\sqrt{abc+4}$ when $ a^2+b^2+c^2=3.$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, buffalo-way

Let $a,b,c\ge 0: a^2+b^2+c^2=3.$ Prove that$$\color{black}{\sqrt{a+4b}+\sqrt{b+4c}+\sqrt{c+4a}\le 3\sqrt{abc+4}. }$$

Naturally, I use Cauchy-Schwarz as
$$\sqrt{a+4b}+\sqrt{b+4c}+\sqrt{c+4a}\le \sqrt{15(a+b+c)},$$
but
$$\color{black}{15(a+b+c)\le 9abc+36,}$$
is already wrong when $a=b=\sqrt{\dfrac{3}{2}}; c=0.$

Hope you help me give some ideas and how it motivates a proof.

Comment: Can someone, which want to close this topic ,explain us, why did you do it? If you did not understand, how Dragon boy used C-S, I am ready to explain. Also, Dragon boy says about a  general trouble of this problem: troubles around point $(\sqrt{1.5},\sqrt{1.5},0).$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I think this problem is nice but not easy.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg not the downvoter/closer, but Dragon boy has recently been spamming a lot of inequalities like this one, which have a very similar characteristic. I wonder if they even attempt to put more than 10 min of work into these, before "dumping" them here for you to solve.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. I tried a lot but the problem is too hard.

Comment: Yes, every single inequality that you've posted is extremely hard, yet almost "random". Where do you get these from anyway?

Comment: $\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{a + 4b}{a + 2b + c} \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} (a + 2b + c) \le 9(abc + 4)$ is also true. It is similar to Michael Rozenberg's solution (already upvoted some hours ago).

Answer (score 1):

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a+4b}\leq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+4b}{3a+8b+2c}\sum_{cyc}(3a+8b+2c)}$$ and it's enough to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+4b}{3a+8b+2c}\leq\frac{9(abc+4)}{13(a+b+c)}.$$
The rest is smooth, but my solution is not so nice.

Can you end it now?

Comment: I think BW helps.

Comment: @TATA box Yes, of course.

Comment: Does we need to homogenize at first?

Comment: @TATA box Yes, and to use WA. I tried also $uvw$. It quits very ugly. After symmetrization we can try to get a cubic inequality of $v^2$.

Comment: I've thought that $uvw$ just works for symmetric inequality. It seems interesting.

Comment: @TATA box Symmetrization of cyclic inequalities it's a very strong way. By this way  we can get sometimes best estimations.